# Preventing ProGuard from evaluating mathematical expressions and removing unused instructions in Android

Tags: android, android-proguard

i am learning how to use ProGuard in Android and what i noticed after decompiling a debug APK (built with ProGuard use) is that ProGuard removes the unused instructions and also evaluates mathematical expressions, for example:
if i use this line of code before using ProGuard:

```
Integer JunkCode6666 = new Integer(Integer.MIN_VALUE+Integer.MAX_VALUE+1);
```

it becomes like this after using ProGuard:

```
num = new Integer(0);
```

i want to know if there is a way to keep the original way, this is for obfuscation purposes. And if there is a way to prevent ProGuard from removing unused instructions. Thank you.

Comment: are you sure that's proguard and not just the compiler?

Comment: well, that makes sense now. I think it might be the compiler not proguard.

Comment: as far as I know the compiler will evaluate _constant_ expressions, and that's something that doesn't make much sense to prevent

Comment: If you want to prevent removal of junk instructions, disable optimizations (via `-dontoptimize` or individual optimization toggles).

Btw, as long as your question does not have any answers, I recommend you to promptly edit it to remove the parts, that no longer trouble you or have been answered in comments (do not do that after someone already posted an answer!) If one of your sub-questions is fully answered in comments, that makes it look like the whole question is solved and significantly reduces probability of more answers coming. Ideally, do not post multi-problem questions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked by compiling this class *without* proguard

```
public class Foo {

    final Integer bar = new Integer(Integer.MIN_VALUE+Integer.MAX_VALUE+1);

}
```

and the compile constructor was

```
  public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 1 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 3 L1
    ALOAD 0
    NEW java/lang/Integer
    DUP
    ICONST_0 // <--- evaluated expression result
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Integer.<init> (I)V
    PUTFIELD Foo.bar : Ljava/lang/Integer;
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE this LFoo; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 4
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

So that it is not proguard that is doing it but the Java compiler, this is happening because the value in the constructor of `Integer` is a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) and is evaluated at compile time for optimization.

You could check, for instance, that compiling this other version of the class

```
public class Foo {

    final Integer bar = new Integer(getA()+getB()+1);

    private int getA(){
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    private int getB(){
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}
```

will result in a different constructor

```
  public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 1 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 3 L1
    ALOAD 0
    NEW java/lang/Integer
    DUP
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL Foo.getA ()I
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL Foo.getB ()I
    IADD
    ICONST_1
    IADD
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Integer.<init> (I)V
    PUTFIELD Foo.bar : Ljava/lang/Integer;
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE this LFoo; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 5
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

As you can see, in this second version the 2 additions are actually performed because the values are obtained from a method invocation and therefore are not constant anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.